# Next-i18Next localpath value doesn't work on built

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization, vercel, i18next

I am trying to build my NextJs application which is using next-i18next. My translation json files are located in the public->static->locales folder. This is code that I am configuring the i18 with:

```
const NextI18Next = require("next-i18next").default;

const path = require("path");

module.exports = new NextI18Next({
 defaultLanguage: "fr",
 otherLanguages: ["en"],
 localePath: path.resolve("./public/static/locales"),
});
```

On the other hand I am getting this error message when I run npm run build:

> Build error occurred
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\User\vfd-hotel\client\C:\Users\User\vfd-hotel\client\public\locales\fr'

It basically uses the basic path twice. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

(I already tried to change the path to just ./public/static/locales but it won't work in production Vercel)